# Javascript Namespaces, onclick Event, et al

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

Is this

```
<input type="button" value="..." 
  onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/Pages/Home.aspx}' ) }"
/>
```

the same (functionally) as

```
. . .
<script type="javascript/text>
  function runIt() {
    ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/Pages/Home.aspx}' );
  }
</script>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="..." 
      onclick="runIt();" />
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really understand

1. what role the term "javascript:" in the `onclick` event description serves. I mean, isn't it the default that what is in the onclick will be javascript?
2. what role the outer curly braces serve in the `..."javascript: {}"`.
3. I recognize that "`ddwrt:`" is a namespace, but I am not aware of how to specify a namespace within a javascript function, which itself is located within a `<script>` block.

Comment: Don't the outer curly braces in the inline version serve to create an object which has a single field ddwrt to which it then assigns the outcome of the GenFireServerEvent function? (The object would subsequently be discarded so I don't know what purpose it serves, but still)

Comment: @Bart, nope, it is parsed as a statement block containing a label (`ddwrt:`) followed by a function call (`GenFireServerEvent(...)`). Note that surrounding the braces with parentheses or applying an operator would change that story.

Comment: Is that because it's not being assigned to anything? Is that what makes the difference between parsing it as an object and parsing it as a block?

Comment: @Bart, preemptively answered in my previous comment :)

Comment: So then, Frédéric, what purpose or function does the label serve?

Comment: Also, Frédéric, what would it take to duplicate within a function, the behavior of the inline syntax?

Answer (score 4):

1. It is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), and completely useless in this context
2. They create a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), also useless in this context
3. No, it is another label and also useless

Comment: You're right, the last part of my comment was wrong. The third case is also parsed as a label.

Comment: So Quentin, ...="javascript: GenFrSvrEv('__cmt;__redir={/Home.aspx}' )" (abbrev'd for the purpose of this post) would operate the same?

Comment: `onclick="GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/Pages/Home.aspx}')"`
 would operate the same.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case (Sharepoint) this is NOT javascript, this is parsed by Sharepoint and translated in something like:

```
onclick="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl37$g_c251e0c4_cd3d_4fc0_9028_ab565452bedd','__cancel;__redirect={https://....}')"
```

have a look at the result source code.
That's why you can't call GenFireServerEvent in your javascript code.